# Can I override iPhone caller interface with custom interface

Tags: ios, iphone, calllog

I'm trying to build a application in which i want override iPhone caller interface with custom interface,as it's possible? Any idea.Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make custom view but not customize iPhone caller interface. Apple not allow to do this.